# Link a prettyphoto including an iframe from a parent page

Tags: variables, hyperlink, prettyphoto

I try to write a link from a first page that will open a second page that includes prettyphoto and automaticaly open the prettyphoto plugin including a third page. Doing that, I've got to transmit a variable from the first link and retrieve it in the third.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is: If the first an the third website were running on the same server you wil be able to use HTML5 Web Storage or Cookies. Here's an example (HTML5 Webstorage):

```
// Save...
localStorage.setItem('item', myVariable);
// Open...
var myVariable = localStorage.getItem('item');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following issue

I added a variable into the link of the first page

```
mypage.php?my_variable=<? echo $id; ?>
```

and on the second page, test the presence of this variable to implante an automatic launch of prettyphoto into the jQuery function init :

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['my_variable'])) {
$id = $_GET['my_variable'];
?>
$.prettyPhoto.open('third_page.php?id=<?PHP echo $id; ?>&ie=UTF-8&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;   q=prettyphoto&amp;iframe=true&amp;width=100%&amp;height=100%');
<?PHP
}
?>
```

I'm now looking for a full screen prettyphoto auto opening, but that's another problem, the main problem is solved for me.